# Transformation of generic classes to XML Schema for Java web services

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

In my application I have many tables with pagination, so I created a class to hold the partial list of results and the total number of results for a paginated query:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "paginatedList")
public class PaginatedList<T> implements Serializable {
    private List<T> results;
    private Integer totalSize;

    @XmlElement(name = "result")
    public List<T> getResults() {
        return this.results;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "totalSize")
    public int getTotalSize() {
        return totalSize;
    }

    // Setters, constructors, etc.
}
```

Then I expose the following method to an EJB:

```
PaginatedList<EmployeeType> getPaginatedList();
```

Additionally, I expose this method with a Web service. But the generated XSD for the web service response loses the type information (`EmployeeType`):

```
<xs:complexType name="getPaginatedListResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="return" type="tns:paginatedList" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="paginatedList">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="result" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
       <xs:element name="totalSize" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I understand that this may happen because of type erasure, but if I return just the list as below:

```
List<EmployeeType> getList();
```

I get a much better XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="getListResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="return" type="tns:employeeType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="employeeType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So the question is this: What should I do in order not to lose the type information from the response of my web service? Is there any JAXB magic I should do in order to "simulate" the XSD generation of List. Any recommendations are welcome.

If it makes any difference, I'm using Weblogic 10.3 to deploy my project.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess - would making the `PaginatedList` to an interface make a difference ?

So make an interface `IPaginatedList<T>` have the `IPaginatedList<EmployeeType> getPaginatedList();` and have `public class PaginatedList<T> implements Serializable, IPaginatedList` (or rename your class to `PaginatedListImpl<T> implements Serializable, IPaginatedList` and leave PaginatedList as an interface - whatever is easier to change (probably the second))

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No, it does not make any difference. If I expose the `IPaginatedList<EmployeeType> getPaginatedList()` method to the web service, I get an error that JAXB cannot handle interfaces. If I use the instructions from this page: https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html, I no longer get an error, but the generated xsd for paginated list contains the `type="xs:anyType"` attribute.

Comment: Maybe then have `PaginatedList<T>` extend [`AbstractList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) so essentially your PaginatedList<T> is just a List - and have `List<EmployeeType> getPaginatedList();`

Comment: This way I lose the totalSize parameter :-(. Even if I change it to `PaginatedList<EmployeeType> getPaginatedList()`;